# jQuery, how to select dynamically generated html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html dynamically generated by the Javascript code below it,

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="student">
    <td class="missed-col">0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Code that generates the html above,

```html
var $tbody = $('tbody');
var $row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('student');
var $nameCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('name-col').text(name);
var $missedCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('missed-col').text('0');
$row.append($nameCol);
$row.append($missedCol);
$tbody.append($row);
```

Then, I want to insert one more line before the missed-col class. And for some reason, I cannot reference $missedCol in the code above as the code jumps into a different function block. So, I did the following,

```html
$('<td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>').insertBefore($('tbody tr .missed-col'));
```

However, it does not work. I see the reason is jQuery is not able to select dynamically generated element this way. I have found some similar questions posted online, but cannot find a good answer.

Comment: the insert before will only work AFTER you append the element on the page

Comment: you dont need to pass the jquery object for `insertBefore()` , instead just pass the selector . like this`$('<td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>').insertBefore('tbody tr .missed-col');`

Comment: try to use this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp, give it 300ms time, worked for me before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the selector to `insertBefore()` instead of passing the `jquery` object, as it is a overkill.

**HTML CODE:**

```
$('<td class="attend-col">3</td>').insertBefore('tbody tr .missed-col');
```

[Working demo @ jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/rqouaz96/)

Comment: The jQuery doco says that you can pass a jQuery object, as confirmed by this update to your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rqouaz96/1/

Comment: hmmm, may be that was not the issue i guess but still passing jquery object is a overkill

Comment: Thank you @dreamweiver! Can you let me know more details what is this about that pass just the target selector rather than the jquery object. This does work for me, I just want to read more about it.

Comment: your welcome. the code works with jquery object as well, so i am not sure why that didnt work for you .may be @nnnnnn can provide more inputs on this.

Comment: passing `jquery` object creates an additional overhead for the JS engine to instantiate a jquery object out of the selector  and pass the reference to `insertBefore`. this is totally unnecessary since `.insertBefore()` is a jquery function , so you dont need to pass a jquery object instance to it.

Comment: I agree that it is certainly better to just pass the selector string, but it should make no difference with regard to whether it works at all (as was easily demonstrated in your fiddle).

Comment: yep, i totally agree with you @nnnnnn. but as per OP just passing selector worked compared to passing jquery object, so do you think using older version of jquery would have caused the problem or any other thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Using LIVE or ON method can you achieve what you want
http://api.jquery.com/live/

below is simple example for that

```js
var counter = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
    $("h2").append("<p class='test'>click me " + (++counter) + "</p>")
});

// With on():

$("h2").on("click", "p.test", function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
<button>generate new element</button>
```

Comment: But...the OP's code doesn't have any event handlers in it, and the question doesn't mention doing anything in response to a click.

Answer (score 0):

I had no prblem with this code onces place into a `$(document)ready` and replacing the `tbody` with a `table`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $tbody = $('table');
  var $row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('student');
  var $nameCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('name-col').text("test");
  var $missedCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('missed-col').text('0');
  $row.append($nameCol);
  $row.append($missedCol);
  $tbody.append($row);

  $('<td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>').insertBefore('table tr .missed-col');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
</table>
```

Comment: Why did you replace `tbody` with `table`? Your code works either way, doesn't it?

Comment: actually not, I don't know if it's the SO fiddle or what but the tbody element is not rendered, maybe if nested in a table element. But the problem is definitely there

Comment: Before I commented I had clicked "edit" on your question, changed it back to `tbody`, and run the snippet, and it worked. (I didn't save it, obviously, but it was an easy way to test the difference, and it worked either way.)

Comment: @nnnnnn `tbody` not wrapped in a `table` definitely does not work on my Chrome

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant the `tbody` *selector* works in the `.insertBefore()`. I didn't notice the other change, because I assumed the OP was appending their `<tbody>` element to a `<table>` (the question doesn't show it being appended to anything).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at snippet..

```js
$(function(){
var $tbody = $('tbody');
var $row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('student');
var $nameCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('name-col').text(name);
var $missedCol = $('<td></td>').addClass('missed-col').text('0');
$row.append($nameCol);
$row.append($missedCol);
$tbody.append($row);
console.log($tbody.find(".student"));
//below line did the trick 
$('<td class="attend-col"><input type="checkbox"></td>').insertBefore($tbody.find("tr .missed-col"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr class="student">
    <td class="missed-col">0</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```